# What's the differece between of link to a dynamic file and as a input object?

Tags: c++, g++, linkage

I use g++ to link my project (an executable mono_kitti) and my project is dependent on a thirdparty library Pangolin. When I do the link action with -lpangolin option:

```
g++ -L../../lib -lORB_SLAM2 -lpangolin mono_kitti.o -o mono_kitti
```

it returns:

```
mono_kitti.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for pangolin::Handler'
mono_kitti.o:(.data+0x8): undefined reference to `vtable for pangolin::HandlerScroll'
mono_kitti.o: In function `pangolin::Handler::~Handler()':
mono_kitti.cc:(.text._ZN8pangolin7HandlerD2Ev[_ZN8pangolin7HandlerD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for pangolin::Handler'
mono_kitti.o: In function `pangolin::HandlerScroll::~HandlerScroll()':
mono_kitti.cc:(.text._ZN8pangolin13HandlerScrollD2Ev[_ZN8pangolin13HandlerScrollD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for pangolin::HandlerScroll'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But When I use this command:

```
g++ -L../../lib -lORB_SLAM2 mono_kitti.o /usr/local/lib/libpangolin.so -o mono_kitti
```

it succeeded.

But it failed again when I tried to swap the order of them:

```
g++ -L../../lib -lORB_SLAM2 /usr/local/lib/libpangolin.so mono_kitti.o -o mono_kitti
```

and returns things identical with the first case above (-lpangolin option).

I'm very confused about these results, could someone can explain the differece between them? Many thanks!

Comment: Order matters, put libraries *after* object files on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the linker sees the library (the `-lpangolin` option in your case), it doesn't yet have any unresolved references to that library, so it discards it.

If you put the object file before the library, so your command line look like e.g.

```
g++ mono_kitti.o -L../../lib -lORB_SLAM2 -lpangolin -o mono_kitti
```

Then the linker have all the unresolved references from `mono_kitti.o` and will pull them from the libraries.